# jQuery mobile scroll to element on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, scrollto

I'm working on a jQuery mobile site that uses the jQuery mobile popup widget.  Inside my popups I have several form elements.  I have my popup configured to scroll on the y axis if the contents cannot fit on the screen.

The problem I'm running into is when the user is on a mobile device and selects a form element towards the bottom of the popup the native keyboard cuts off the form element the user just selected.

I realize the user can just manually scroll to the element again but, I want to make it a better experience for the user.  The only way I could think to solve this would be programatically scrolling to each form element once the user bring the element into focus.  Below is the code I have been working on but, I just can't get it to work.  My console log keeps showing the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

here is the code I'm using:

```
$('#popup input, #popup textarea').focusin(function() {
    var container = $('#popup'),
    scrollTo = $(this);

    container.scrollTop(
        scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
    );
});
```

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong target.  My original code was using `$(this)` and it should have been using `$(e.target)` instead.

```
$('#popup input, #popup textarea').focusin(function(e) {
        var container = $('#popup'),
        scrollTo = $(e.target);

        container.animate({
            scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top
        }, 300);    
});
```

This code only worked part of the way.  I had to use the same code on the window resize event in order to capture the correct offset when the keyboard slides out